# Why is # char before URL fragment encoded by stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding?

Tags: ios, url-encoding

Isn't # a legal character when used to specify fragment in URL?

Then why `[@"http://google.com#abc" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` returns `@"http://google.com%23abc"` instead of `@"http://google.com#abc"`?

Comment: I only use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` on URL parameter values I'm using to build the URL, not the whole URL.

Answer (score 1):

The `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` method cannot easily determine that the `#` in the string is a valid indication that the fragment will follow, or whether it was, for example, part of some query in which it should percent escape it:

```
http://google.com?q=#1
```

So, in your example, you wouldn't want it percent escaped, but in the above example (where you wanted to specify the value `#1` for the parameter named `q`) you would.

I must agree, though, that it is curious that they percent escape `#` but not `&` or `+`.

For greater control over what characters are percent escaped and which are not, you may want to consider `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` or `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`.

For example, if you wanted to apply the standard percent escaping logic, but leave the `#` characters unescaped, you could do:

```
NSString *escaped = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                              (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                              CFSTR("#"),
                                                                              NULL,
                                                                              kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
```

This obviously assumes that the `#` will never occur in the query before the fragment.

The more generalized solution would apply different percent-escaping logic to the various components of the URL (what's allowed as separators between the components are not allowed within the individual components).

Comment: Thanks. I know all those you mentioned. I just want to confirm that the APIs are broken not my understanding of URL because they treats legally used character as illegal. Even you example of `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` does not make much sense since `charactersToLeaveUnescaped` is "Characters whose percent escape sequences you want to leave intact. Pass NULL to specify that all illegal characters be escaped." Since "#" is legally used here one should not have to include it in `charactersToLeaveUnescaped`.

Comment: For the purposes of `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` (and `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`, for that matter), the `#` is a character that will be escaped. Thus, if you don't want it to be escaped, you must include it in the `charactersToLeaveUnescaped`, plain and simple. I'm not going to defend Apple's choice of characters to consider "legal", i.e. those they escape and those they don't; their implementation is pure silliness, not in conformance with RFC 3986, as they claim). IMHO, this greatly diminishes the value of `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`.

Comment: I suspect that there is some awareness of this muddled implementation when you look at the new (as of iOS 7) method, `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`. This cuts the Gordian knot, leaving it entirely up to the developer to pick which characters to escape and which to not escape.

Comment: I see. This kind of API is usable but not very useful. I wish  at least document them better. Currently `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` is well documented. However, if one read document of `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` and follow it to `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` and read the sample in its Discussion, one would be mislead to assume that using `CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` followed by `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` would give a perfectly percent-encoded URL string.

Comment: As you mentioned "The more generalized solution would apply different percent-escaping logic to the various components of the URL", I want to point out that `NSURLComponents` is also a seeming-perfect solution until one realize the one can not even create a `NSURLComponents`(same for `NSURL`) without first doing necessary percent-encoding of the URL string. So URL components are need to do perfect URL encoding but `NSURLComponents` is not available without URL encoding the string first… chicken & egg.